# <strong> crea un espacio automaticamente después de la palabra

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8, tinymce

Hola estoy desarollando una webapp para un blog, en Laravel y para el editor de texto estoy utilizando TinyMCE. Al momento de verificar mi post me percaté que la etiqueta  creaba un espacio después de la palabra, el resultado después de inspeccionar la página es:

```
<p><strong>Bold </strong>
```

Volvi al editor para fijarme si de casualiad se me había escapado un espacio, pero no. Chequé el CSS y no tengo ninguna regla que indique un padding, o lo que fuera. Asi es como estoy renderizando el cuerpo del post:

```
    <div class="single-post">
        <img src="{{asset('/storage/img/post_uploads/'.$post->image_url) }}" alt="postimage"/> 
        <h1 class="header-post"> {{ $post->title }} </h1>
        <div> {!! $post->body !!} </div>
           ....
    </div> <!-- Single post end -->
```

Creo que no es un comportamiento que rompa la aplicación pero si creo que rompería con el estilo de diseño del front end, y esto ocurriría cada vez que un texto negritas ese presente.

Comment: cuando transformas el texto en negrita, estás seguro que no se selecciona automáticamente el espacio en blanco a continuación de la palabra?

Comment: Haz un dd($post->body) mira si no viene desde tu base el espacio vacío

Comment: Hola, gracias por comentar, no me parece que pueda encontrar una solución, pienso debe ser algo en cuanto a TinyMCE ya que inserta varias etiquetas HTML y como mencionaba aún si verifico en mi función de editar y quito algun espacio, sigue apareciendo. Intentaré aplicar una regla CSS en específico para la etiqueta.